# Zend 2 CSV Action

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have created the following action, which successfully returns a CSV. however it still returns the layout within the response. From what i have read the layout is not supposed to be returned. aAnyone know how to disable this?

```
public function csvAction() {

    $content = 'test';
    $response = $this->getResponse();

    $response->getHeaders()
             ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
             ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"my_filen.csv\"")
             ->addHeaderLine('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
             ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($content));

    $response->setContent($content);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code in one of my controllers (from the ZendSkeletonApp) and it works as expected. You may have some mis-configuration in your setup.

Comment: returning the response object inside your action shurtcuts the process and doesn't render the layout, something must be up as said above.

Comment: Look at your view config array... something is wrong.

Comment: wanted to ask that what is 'test'.And tried to execute your code.I am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function addHeaderLine() on a non-object ` can you please specify them in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these at the beginning of your csvAction function:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

Comment: This solution is for ZF1, not ZF2